# Woocomerce hide parent description when display variation description

Tags: javascript, html, css, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

Hello i have a issue with a woocommerce site styled with elementor.

I have parent products with variations. Now i need to hide the parent product long-description when i select the variation product. The variation product description should be display where the parent description was. Now the variation description overlays the parent description.

[image]

The idea is to hinde the div:

```
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-eb99509 elementor-widget elementor-widget-woocommerce-product-content" data-id="eb99509" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="woocommerce-product-content.default">
```

if the following div has no style:

```
<div class="woocommerce-variation single_variation" style="display: none;">
```

If i choose NO variation the div above becomes the style "display:none"

Im sorry for being such ja javascript / jquery noop ;)

Comment: Do you have the link to the page?

Comment: Sure :)) https://0x1.hashtag-assist.de/produkt/malkovic/ you need to select a variation then you see the overlaying div. Let me know If i can do anything, like moving the divs for better inspection

Comment: Hmmm. Not easy to say without looking at the backend on how it is added. I feel there would be a standard way of editing this without using Elementor because WooCommerce already has it by default in the theme.

Comment: The problem is that elementor shows the parent descripton within the "product content" widget but the variation description within the "add to cart" widget.. there is no way that the parent description become invisible if a variation is selected. I will ask elementor support aswell. Thank you for your time!!!